# How to add content header to exporting files using Flask and Python

Tags: python, flask

Am trying to export database records to file.csv. I can successfully export data but am having issues with the exported content
not properly converted to csv format.

Do I need something like  `mimetype = 'text/csv'` or what?.

If yes were or how do I add it to the code below. what are other possible options/solutions

```
#list of mime file types
#https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type
import csv
#db connections
@app.route('/export_csv', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def export_csv():

    mycursor = db1.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    f = csv.writer(open("file.csv", "w"))
    for row in myresult: 

        f.writerow([str(row)])
    return 'success'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issue with `out.writerow()` function as per code below and desired csv is outputed.

Thanks

```
 out.writerow([ row[0], row[1]])
```